# How can I get a list of files changed using the p4 plugin in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have a list of projects in an jenkins pipeline.

I am only interested in rebuilding projects which are changed

so I am trying to get a list changes on files using the p4 plugin to do so.

Is this possible? I use the configure pipeline page to configure p4 settings

and I cant run the pipeline from the jenkins file because I am not allowed to remove the groovy sandbox

https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/docs/P4GROOVY.md

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: I had to write a script in the jenkins file then

Comment: is there a doc for the script/can you share it?